# ¿Qué oración o palabra puede emplearse para traducir al español la palabra "Wrapper", utilizada en los lenguajes de programación?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

Es frecuente para las personas hispanoparlantes que se encuentran aprendiendo o expandiendo sus conocimientos en un lenguaje de programación consulten libros o páginas web en el idioma inglés. Sin embargo, en algunas ocasiones es complicado traducir al español determinados términos, ya que una palabra en inglés puede requerir el uso de una o más oraciones para traducir esa palabra al español. Un ejemplo de ello es la palabra “Wrapper” ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293752/where-and-how-is-the-term-used-wrapper-in-programming-what-does-it-help-to-do), [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4389/wrapper-software-engineering#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20software,means%20of%20well%2Ddefined%20interfaces.), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744562/what-does-wrapping-mean-in-programming), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function)). ¿Cómo se puede traducir al español la palabra Wrapper, usada en lenguajes de programación como C++ y Python?

Agradezco su apoyo para contestar mi pregunta.

Comment: @mdewey, totalmente de acuerdo. He corregido la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrapper**

Wrapper como envolver, envoltura, envolvente, embalaje, contenedor, subrutina, subprograma, función contenedora, adaptador, decoradores, encapsuladores, cierre...

**Wrapper** que recibe el nombre de **contenedor** o función contenedora que activa otra función, como clase **envolvente** que contiene dentro una llamada a otro objeto, como "**Facade**" (Fachada), clase/objeto que se envuelve alrededor de otro objeto, también como "**Decorator**" (Decorador), como clase/objeto que se envuelve en tiempo de ejecución alrededor de otro.

En general el concepto de "**wrapper**" como **envoltorio** o envoltorios que "*encierran la funcionalidad de algo con otra cosa*" esta bastante clara y definida (capa exterior que rodea o envuelve una cosa), y por otra parte como se ha señalado más arriba, ya existen muchos otros apelativos que le han dado nombre.

A partir de aquí encontrar otra denominación para "**wrapper**", es volver al origen del concepto, en el que hay que tener en cuenta o añadir alguna de las características más importantes de ese "*nuevo contenedor*",​ como un "todo" o "recipiente", que une la integralidad y la compatibilidad que hacen que sus elementos internos trabajen anexos, ya que una de las peculiaridades de estos "envoltorios" es la de permitir que clases incompatibles trabajen de manera conjunta.

La palabra "**wrap**" por sí, puede hacer referencia a un abrigo, a una bata, a una camisa..., es decir, da la idea de que cubre algo y que a su vez al cubrir, también oculta. Así figurativamente "wrap", puede ser guardar algo secreto o simplemente no revelar algo, por ello "**wrapper**" recibe el nombre de envoltura, embalaje, contenedor, cierre... ya que "**envolver**" es algo que se pone al "**abrigo**" de otra cosa, cerrar o cubrir con otra cosa, "fuera de la vista de", es "poner una máscara a", una forma de enmascarar algo o al amparo de otra.

De esta manera, se trataría de encontrar una palabra en español, no tanto en el sentido de cubrir u ocultar algo, sino más bien que pudiera relacionar tanto al **envoltorio** como a lo **envuelto**, al **contenido** como al **continente**, una especie de conjunto o al menos una locución que hiciera referencia a dos zonas o partes distintas y que sitúen la acción o sentido dentro de la misma palabra, pues el término "wrapper" por sí mismo, no parece que desarrolle la noción de módulo integrado, a no ser que se acompañe en su forma descriptiva, como función contenedora (wrapper function), clase envolvente o contenedora (wrapper class)... que da idea de una capacidad más amplia.

Inicialmente en español podríamos pensar en algo que "**cobija**", como una especie de cubierta que protege alguna cosa. Un "**cobertor**" como cobertura que "abriga" o recoge a otra.

Igualmente serían candidatas palabras como "**frazada**" especie de manta que "cubre", "**frisa**" en el sentido de que sirve como forro y por tanto de protección de otra, "**frisa informática**". Por último probaríamos con la palabra "**berma**" que hace referencia a una especie de **barrera que separa dos zonas** y quizás estaríamos cerca de conseguir nuestro objetivo, sin embargo, ninguna de estas locuciones, aún añadiéndole un identificativo concepto informático como es "**lógica**" o "**inteligente**", ejem. "**berma lógica**", "**berma inteligente**", conseguiría incorporar la imagen única de "**continente**" y "**contenido**", a especie de "**contenedor unitario**" que agrupara el conjunto que se pretende sintetizar.

---

### El concepto trincaje y estiba

Siguiendo estos parámetros, mantendríamos la sensatez de dirigirnos al propio ámbito del "**contenedor**" como recipiente de carga y porte de varios elementos, descubriendo en esa lógica los criterios necesarios que comparten distintas variables y en ellos la locución "**trincaje**".

Trincaje como un concepto "general" de técnicas referentes tanto al **continente** como al **contenido**, a fin de recoger y remitir conjuntamente los elementos que integran a ambos en cuanto a la adecuación de las "mercancías", pues "mercancias" también son datos y elementos, estableciéndose para nosotros de forma figurada, "**trincaje**", como "mercancías, información, actividad, acciones" de una "clase contenedora" y de los componentes o elementos que aparecen en una "wrapper", es decir, en este caso el "**trincaje**" integraría tanto el **contenido** como el **continente**, el **envoltorio** como lo **envuelto** o aquello que se quiere cubrir, pues de esta forma se resuelve el problema de coexistencia de clases incompatibles dentro del concepto y atiende a un único módulo íntegro.

A partir de este concepto, "**trincaje**", se puede desarrollar el "**trincaje con valores electrónicos o informáticos**" que atiendan a la lógica de subrutinas, datos, valores, funciones, factores, objetos, métodos... junto a otro concepto, el de "**estiba**"  como distribuidor de los elementos miembros (de esa mercancía figurada) dentro de un "trincaje", que es el que tiene capacidad para fijar, asegurar y consolidar las distintas partes integrantes.

**P.D**. Por lo abismal que pueda el tema parecer, es aconsejable repetir la lectura un par de veces. Esto no deja de ser una mera especulación que solo intenta mejorar la comprensión que desde el español tenemos del concepto "wrapper" y sus competencias. De todas formas siempre te quedará la opción de dirigirte a ella como función de retorno.

Answer (score 2):

Nadie la traduce. La “prueba del algodón” es la Wikipedia en francés, donde tampoco se traduce.

Se puede explicar como “envoltorio” o “adaptador”, pero todo intento de establecer una traducción está condenado al fracaso.

Aunque, ya puestos, y siguiendo nuestras buenas costumbres, yo la llamaría “ráper”.